# stripe test api Network Error

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments

I am going through [this tutorial](https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/custom-checkout#run-the-application) on stripe to set up checkout with node.js, but when I try to run the app, the fetch fails. I get `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.`

I am using the test api keys and using firefox. It seems like it might be an issue with the test api key, but I'm not sure. Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you install the stripe library? You may have skipped the beginning of step 1.

Comment: This could mean a lot of things.  I suspect you'll need to include more context from your working code.  Where does that error get raised for instance.  Is there a stack trace around?